# Select List from List in ViewModel presenting options as "[object Window]"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I would like to create a select list on my view that allows the client to chose the customer from that select list.

My view model looks like this:

```
public int SalesOrderId { get; set; }
public int CustomerId { get; set; }
public string PONumber { get; set; }
public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
public List<SalesOrderItemViewModel> SalesOrderItems { get; set; }
```

My Customer model looks like this:

```
public int CustomerId { get; set; }
public string CustomerName { get; set; }
```

My knockout js looks like this:

```
SalesOrderViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    // This automatically creates my view model properties for ko from my view model passed from the server
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, salesOrderItemMapping, self);

    // .... Other save functions etc.
};
```

**[Edit]**
Sales Item mappings as requested

```
var salesOrderItemMapping = {
    'SalesOrderItems': {
        // key for each child
        key: function (salesOrderItem) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(salesOrderItem.SalesOrderItemId);
        },
        // Tell knockout what to fo for each sales order item it needs to create
        create: function (options) {
            // create a new sales order item view model using the model passed to the mapping definition
            return new SalesOrderItemViewModel(options.data); // Notice data is a property of the options object
            // Moreover, data is the data for this child and options is the object containing the parent
        }
    }
};
```

**[Edit]**
@Html.Raw(data) as requested:

```
{"SalesOrderId":1,"CustomerId":1,"PONumber":"123456","OrderDate":"2015-01-25T00:00:00","MessageToClient":"The original value of Customer Name is Ashfield Clutch Services.","ObjectState":0,"Customer":{"CustomerId":1,"CustomerName":"Ashfield Clutch Services"},"SalesOrderItems":[{"SalesOrderItemId":1,"ProductCode":"ABC","Quantity":10,"UnitPrice":1.23,"SalesOrderId":1,"ObjectState":0},{"SalesOrderItemId":2,"ProductCode":"XYZ","Quantity":7,"UnitPrice":14.57,"SalesOrderId":1,"ObjectState":0},{"SalesOrderItemId":3,"ProductCode":"SAMPLE","Quantity":3,"UnitPrice":15.00,"SalesOrderId":1,"ObjectState":0}],"SalesOrderItemsToDelete":[],"Customers":[{"CustomerId":1,"CustomerName":"Ashfield Clutch Services"},{"CustomerId":3,"CustomerName":"Davcom-IT Ltd"},{"CustomerId":2,"CustomerName":"Fluid Air Conditioning"}]}
```

And at the top of my view I have this js:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/salesOrderViewModel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var salesOrderViewModel = new SalesOrderViewModel(@Html.Raw(data));
    ko.applyBindings(salesOrderViewModel);
</script>
```

If I bind my select list to the `Customers` collection in my view model the select list doesn't appear to be bound correctly:

```html
<select class="form-control" name="Customers" id="Customers" data-bind="options: Customers, optionsText: CustomerName, optionsValue: CustomerId, value: CustomerId"></select>
```

[image: screenshot]

You can see that instead of showing the customers it shows "`[object Window]`" for all of the customers. I think it could be half way there as it shows the correct number of "`[object Window]`" vs the number of clients in the db.

I understand that the Customers must be a knockout observable array but I'm not sure how to apply this to my js view model.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What all properties you have in Customer class?

Comment: Right now just: `int CustomerId {get; set;}` and `string CustomerName { get; set; }`

Comment: When you are getting values form server what is coming in to Customers? It may be something like data.Customers. I asked you about customer class's properties because Object error come when there is mismach between Property name from server and attached value in Select.

Comment: I populate Customers in the controller from the repository before I return the view model to the view. So in effect the view model contains the current sales order, all it's child sales order entities and a collection of customers. It cannot be data.Customers as we're no longer in the js function when binding to the select list so data is undefined at that moment.

Comment: So dio you mean Customers is part of salesOrderViewModel from ko.applyBindings(salesOrderViewModel);

Comment: Yes, that's correct Dnyanesh.

Comment: We need to see your `salesOrderItemMapping` as well as the *rendered* version of `@Html.Raw(data)` to be able to properly repro your situation / help.

Comment: I guessed it could be to do with the fact that the customers were not mapped in the ko.mapping so I added `'Customers': {
        key: function (customer) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(customer.CustomerId);
        }
    }` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arent you missing "" in options text and options value ?

```
<select class="form-control" name="Customers" id="Customers" data-bind="options: Customers, optionsText: "CustomerName", optionsValue: "CustomerId", value: CustomerId"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer got me 80% of the way but in the context of the question, I guess it is the correct answer. Your answer displayed the customers as asked but the binding to the salesOrderViewModel was not working. `Value` in the `data-bind` should be `salesOrderViewMode.CustomerId`, not just `CustomerId`. Thank you for your help. For completion: `<select class="form-control" name="Customers" id="Customers" data-bind="options: Customers, optionsText: 'CustomerName', optionsValue: 'CustomerId', value: salesOrderViewModel.CustomerId, event: {change: flagSalesOrderAsEdited}"></select>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make one change while binding your customers to select drop down

Your Exisitng Code

```
<select class="form-control" name="Customers" id="Customers" data-bind="options: Customers, optionsText: CustomerName, optionsValue: CustomerId, value: CustomerId"></select>
```

Make following change

```
<select class="form-control" name="Customers" id="Customers" data-bind="options: salesOrderViewModel.Customers, optionsText: Customers.CustomerName, optionsValue: Customers.CustomerId, value: CustomerId"></select>
```

> options: salesOrderViewModel.Customers

And it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks Dnyanesh, this didn't work. I changed it as suggested and the page doesn't load completely now in Firefox and the js console shows an error of _ReferenceError: CustomerName is not defined_

Comment: I'm afraid that does not work either Dnyanesh. Although the select list now has a collection of [object Object] now instead of the previous collection [object Window]. I appreciate you trying to help though.